# some ways of expressing future

Tags: conditional-constructions, future-tense

I have learnt some words can use present tense to express the future.

Like:

***Even if it rains, I will go outside.*** Can I change this one to: **Even if you have jobs to do tomorrow, you are still playing!!!**

***If you booked a ticket, you can enjoy our best service now.*** Can I change this one to: **Even if you booked a ticket, you still can't enjoy the service for some reason.** (Here the past tense is about guessing, not the unreality.）

And about **Even if he had jobs to do tomorrow, he was still playing.Obviously, he was fired.** (Just change the first example to the past, now someone is talking about the reason why he got fired.)

Thanks so much!

Comment: You can use the present tense to express future plans, for something scheduled or arranged.  So your first sentence makes sense if there are plans for the person to play.  The second sentence doesn't really make sense to me; can you explain it better?  I don't understand the third one because it's not about the future, and everything in the sentence is in the past, so I'm not clear on what the question is.

Comment: @moyeea Please capitalize the first word of _all_ the sentences you write in English. That's the way we do it. Also, please end your sentences with a period/full stop (or exclamation mark, or question mark.) Those are the rules!

Comment: I have changed. Help me，please

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  The second sentence like：The restaurant was closed by the government for some reason. Now can I say： Even if you bought a ticket yesterday，you still can't enjoy the food now.  And the third one，I'm talking about the past future. At that time，he would have jobs to do tomorrow，but he was still playing.  Can I say：“Even if he had jobs to do tomorrow， he was still playing. Then he got fired.”

Comment: @moyeea I think this exercise is about understanding and using **Even if.** _Even if_ emphasizes the determination of the speaker to achieve the stated goal or outcome in spite of any obstacle. It can't be "turned on its head" to express a resultant _inability_ to do something, as in your second sentence.

Comment: Your last example calls for _Even **though**,_ not _Even if._